# How To Store Results Of SQL Query In Session

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I was wondering if anyone can help me, what I've been trying to do is after a staff member logs in I want to save their staff_id so it can be used in following forms to identify them, I think I'm supposed to use Session but I'm a bit confused. Here's my current log in form code:

```
Private sql As New sqlcontrol
Private AuthUser As String

Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click

    If sql.HasConnection = True Then
        If IsAuthenticated() = True Then
            AuthUser = tbUsername.Text
            MsgBox("login successful")

            sql.RunQuery("SELECT staff_level FROM staff WHERE staff_username ='" & tbUsername.Text & "'")

            If sql.sqldataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("staff_level") = 1 Then
                staffhome.Show()
                Me.Close()
            ElseIf sql.sqldataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("staff_level") = 2 Then
                adminhome.Show()
                Me.Close()
            End If
        End If
    End If
    'pressing this button checks database for users
End Sub

Private Function IsAuthenticated() As Boolean

    'clear existing records
    If sql.sqldataset IsNot Nothing Then
        sql.sqldataset.Clear()
    End If

    sql.RunQuery("SELECT Count(staff_username) As UserCount FROM staff WHERE staff_username ='" & tbUsername.Text & "' AND staff_password='" & tbPassword.Text & "' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS ")

    If sql.sqldataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("UserCount") = 1 Then
        Return True
    End If

    MsgBox("Invalid Username or Password.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "LOGIN FAILED")
    Return False
    'function checks whether username and password combination exists in database
End Function
```

As I am getting no responses I thought I should add what I've tried to do, I've tried to create a sub that runs a query to get the users staff_id then saves the results of the query to a variable which is then saved to Session by modifying one of my other functions. I doubt this is the right thing to do however I have no other ideas. Here is my attempted code:

Private Sub storeid()

```
   sql.RunQuery("SELECT staff_id FROM staff where username= " & tbUsername.Text & "")

    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("staffid") = sql.sqldataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("staff_id")
End Sub
```

Comment: If your question is how to store something in Session, it looks like you know how to do that. Or is your question something else?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to reinvent a wheel, namely *Forms Authentication*.

> ASP.NET membership and ASP.NET login controls provide a layer of
>   abstraction over forms authentication and replace most or all of the
>   work you would normally have to do to use forms authentication.

Read [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy(v=vs.100).aspx) and try to follow it in your project, put your code in its `Logon_Click()` at logon page. After that, once authenticated, ASP.NET should create a user session that can be used across the application (i.e. no need in custom `IsAuthenticated()` because you will can use the `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` property).

Regarding your code:

- if you don't see any output it might be due the fact that you 
  don't validate all possible cases, e.g.

  what happens if HasConnection=false?

  ```
  If sql.HasConnection = True Then
  ...
  End If
  ```

  you'll get no output.

  what happens if staff_level is NULL?

  ```
  If sql.sqldataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("staff_level") = 1 Then
     staffhome.Show()
     Me.Close()
  ElseIf sql.sqldataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("staff_level") = 2 Then
     adminhome.Show()
     Me.Close()
  End If
  ```

  you'll get no output.
- `Me.Close()` is an attempt to close the current webform? It's a desktop-like coding and it will not close anything in ASP.NET - get rid of it.
- Make sure that `staffhome.Show()` and `adminhome.Show()` work as expected (i.e. redirect to expected pages using `Response.Redirect()` or `Server.Transfer()`). It sounds again like you try to use a desktop-like coding in ASP.NET.
- The code is vulnerable for sql injections